# Google to find my page in english and another language

Tags: search, metadata

It is a little nooby question but i cannot find anywhere a good simple explanation to my question.

So Google inter alia finds your page based on the keywords and description of the page. right?
My firm is located in Italy and have clients all over the world.
So we would like that the page is more visible on google by updating the description and keywords.

Right now, the description of the page is in english. I would like to write two description (italian and english). I was thinking to use something like that:

```
<meta name="Description" lang="ENG" content="content" />
<meta name="Description" lang="ITA" content="contenuto" />
```

I read that this practice is not the best. Is there a better way to do it, or, it doesn't have any importance to have two description of the page?

Also the keywords are in english and italian. Is important that the keywords are in both languages or does google (when searching for your page) use some kind of translate function where searching?

Thanks for any explanation..

Comment: I hoped that at least one will reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add several `meta`-`description` elements with content in different languages by using the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes). The value of the `lang` attribute must be a [BCP 47](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) language tag.

For English, it is "en" (not "ENG"), and for Italian it is "it" (not "ITA").

```html
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="">
<meta name="description" lang="it" content="">
```

(Asking how search engine services handle this is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might ask it on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Note: this is not (yet) allowed in HTML5 ([details](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108392/17633)).